# Количество цвета в градиенте

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Есть ли разница в том, чтобы задать цвет несколько раз или задать его в процентах в градиенте? Влияет ли это на плавность перехода и производительность?
Например, по моей логике, запись `(#fae259,#fae259,#fae259,#080085)` должна быть равносильна записи `(...#fae259 75%,#080085)` (100%/4*3), но это не так, почему?

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрим ваш пример `(#fae259,#fae259,#fae259,#080085)`.

Мы имеем 4 точки, а следовательно, 3 диапазона равной длины. Какие будут значения точек останова в этом случае?
Очевидно, что запись эквивалентна этой:

```
(#fae259 0%, #fae259 33.33%, #fae259 66.66%, #080085 100%)
```

Или этой:

```
(#fae259 66.66%, #080085)
```

Отсюда и различия с `(#fae259 75%, #080085)`.

Answer (score 0):

Что значит "задать цвет несколько раз или задать его в процентах"? Есть разные [виды градиентов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients). Каждый цвет в градиенте характеризуется набором значений:

1. Направление;
2. Цвет (можно с прозрачностью);
3. Точки остановки;

```css
.gradient {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 100%) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255));
}
```

```html
<div class ="gradient">
```

**Внутри функции градиента в процентах задаём точки остановки цвета, а не сам цвет.** Точки останвки можно задать и в пикселях. Если вам нужны чередующиеся цвета - задайте несколько точек остановки:

```css
.multiposition-stops {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: linear-gradient(to left,
   lime 20%, red 30% 45%, cyan 55% 70%, yellow 80% );
}
```

```html
<div class ="multiposition-stops">
```

Comment: Было бы не плохо, если бы вы добавили еще и фрагмент кода.

Comment: @OliverPatterson Разметку? Хорошо, сейчас добавлю.

Comment: Добавил пример в вопросе.